# make $user is undefined Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $user }} with {{ $user ?? '' }}

Tags: php, laravel

I have one-page sidebar.blade.php and I have to import this page in another page as a sidebar
I have variable here that is coming from the controller when I import sidebar to other page using @extends it shows me error undefined variable with solution

" make $user is undefined Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $user }} with {{ $user ?? '' }}"

how I can solve this

sidebar code here

```
@if($user->role  =="handlers" )  
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url('/kontaktuppgifter') }}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> kontaktuppgifter{{-- <span class="fa arrow"></span> --}}</a>

            </li>
            @endif
            <li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Your probably not passing the variable `$user` in to each of your views, but you are extending the sidebar view, try using Laravel `auth()` helper instead to get the user model. You can do something like this:

```
@if(auth()->user()->role  == "handlers")  
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('/kontaktuppgifter') }}">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
            kontaktuppgifter
        </a>
    </li>
@endif
```

You can also share a $user variable with all your views, this way you won't have to query the database each time you want to retrieve the user data.

You can do this in your BaseController class `__construct()` function:

```
//App\Http\Controller.php

public function __construct()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    view()->share('user', $user);
}
```

Then you can use a user variable in your view, just like you are doing right now:

```
@if($user->role  == "handlers")  
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('/kontaktuppgifter') }}">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
            kontaktuppgifter
        </a>
    </li>
@endif
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for help yes mentioned the exact problem $user is not available in each view I can do with auth but in this variable data not from auth. I exactly want that to make a variable available in each view page

Comment: I updated my answer, this way you can share any data with all your views, that are returned from inside any of your controllers.

Comment: for the first solution i got this 
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/EASI/resources/views/layout/sidebar.blade.php)

Comment: I got the solution by this {{ Auth::user()->name }}

Answer (score -1):

If $user is current user, then You should use Auth for that:

```
@if(auth()->user()->role  =="handlers" )  
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url('/kontaktuppgifter') }}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> kontaktuppgifter{{-- <span class="fa arrow"></span> --}}</a>

            </li>
@endif
```

Comment: This variable data not from auth. I exactly want that to make a variable available in each view page

Comment: i got this 
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/EASI/resources/views/layout/sidebar.blade.php)

Comment: I got this {{ Auth::user()->name }}